Relationship between implied swaption volatility and bond yield volatility
What would be a relationship between swaption implied volatility/skew and implied bond yield volatility? How these are comparable and exploitable to trade volatility?

I don't think you can exploit, if even observe this. Bond options are extremely illiquid and unless you trade them with a market maker, you will not see prices (no quotes on Bloomberg etc.). The only thing you will find are bond ETF options but these are so different from (SOFR) swaptions.

I feel that the only thing you can say about them is that they are highly correlated.
